# Require ExcelAPI in Office AddIn manifest

Tags: office-addins, office-store

How can we correctly require the ExcelAPI in the Office AddIn manifest? According to the XML Schema found in the [online docs](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats), the correct form would be:

```
<Requirements> 
  <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
    <Set Name="ExcelApi" MinVersion="1.1"/>
  </Sets>
</Requirements>
```

...as the direct child of ”. When we do this, the error says: “The element 'OfficeApp' has invalid child element 'Requirements'”. What can we do?

Comment: Try changing order of elements, this was the case for Label inside CustomTab for me, Label needed to be in the end of CustomTab for it to be accepted as child.